# iOS: How to highlight a button with a ring of blue fuzzy light?

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton

I need to make a button stand out. It's one of many buttons that the user can press.

In some web interfaces they highlight a button with a ring of fuzzy blue light around it, as if it were blacklighted.

Is there a simple way to do this in native iOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
myButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
```

You'll also need to make sure you didn't set `clipsToBounds` on the button.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom button image and set it for the button you want to stand out. There is no idea of "focus" on iOS so a glowing button isn't really a normal thing for the device.

Comment: That's what I thought. I suppose another alternative is a custom button whose interior background is a different color. That's pretty easy to do.

Comment: If you want to go through more trouble you could create a UIButton subclass and add a "hasFocus" property that would make it draw highlighted.